# Set font size of individual character in WPF TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard, font-size

I'm trying to make an animation where I catch the TextChanged event and make the newly added character to fade from being fontsize 0 to the set size by me.

I have the animation working, but, when I type in a new character the whole contents of the textbox changes with it, but I only want the pressed key.

This is the code I have:

```
private void CreateTextboxAnimation(TextBox box)
    {
        // Info Needed By Control
        double FontSize = box.FontSize;
        //
        DoubleAnimation Anim = new DoubleAnimation();
        Anim.From = 0.0;
        Anim.To = FontSize;
        Anim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        Anim.AutoReverse = false;
        SB = new Storyboard();
        SB.Children.Add(Anim);
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(Anim, box.Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(Anim, new PropertyPath(TextBox.FontSizeProperty));

    }
    private Storyboard SB;

    private void TestBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TestBox.IsLoaded == true)
        {
            SB.Begin(TestBox);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to use a `RichTextBox`. You will be able to manipulate individual characters.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have that level of control over the text using standard text controls in WPF. You will need to delve into the deep world of [`Glyph`s and `GlyphRun`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd941785%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Using this lowest level of functionality, you can have complete control over each character displayed. From the linked page:

> A glyph is a physical representation of a character in a given font. Characters might have many glyphs, with each font on a system potentially defining a different glyph for that character.
>
> A glyph run represents a contiguous set of glyphs that all have the same font face and size, as well as the same client drawing effect, if any.

Here is a good page on MSDN introducing `Glyph`s and `GlyphRun`s which shows some code examples:

[Introduction to the GlyphRun Object and Glyphs Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748985.aspx)

---

UPDATE >>>

The other method that you could have used to increase the size of just part of the text would be to manipulate `Run` elements within the `TextBox`, but I don't think that it would work for text input. Check out the [WPF How to arrange TextBlock with different Fontsize at bottomline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340809/wpf-how-to-arrange-textblock-with-different-fontsize-at-bottomline) post here on StackOverflow for an example of that (just for text output).

Finally, I've just thought that you could do what you want if you create a collection of `char`s and display them in a `ListBox` with a custom animated `StackPanel` with `Orientation="Horizontal"` set as the `ListBox.ItemsPanel`. You could simply animate each item as it is added. Here are a number of useful articles on how to create custom animated panels, starting simply and getting more complex:

[How to create a Custom Layout Panel in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html)
[Creating a sliding panel in WPF](http://bitsbobsetc.wordpress.com/2011/07/10/creating-a-sliding-panel-in-wpf/)
[Animated WPF Panels](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153554/Animated-WPF-Panels)